# Strange issue with wifi (works only with hdmi)

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-4, gui

I have set up wifi connection from GUI and raspi-config. In both cases after reboot rpi does not connect to wifi network. There is one strange thing. If I connect rpi to hdmi it suddenly connects to wifi within 5 seconds.

My wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrlinterface=DIR=/var/run/wpasupplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=PL

network={
ssid="network"
psk="pass"
}
```

dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.8.111/24
static routers=192.168.8.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.8.1
```

Have you any idea how to solve it? Thank you :)

Comment: What's the resolution of your HDMI display? There's a well documented problem with WiFi and 1366x768 displays.

Comment: wouldn't the resolution of the HDMI be irrelevant if it's not connected when the issue occurs?